# How can I change the tooltip color or font in Ambiance?

Tags: 10.04, gtk, accessibility, ambiance

I'm using the Ambiance theme in Ubuntu 10.04 which I am generally quite happy with but I would like to change the tooltip color or font. I sometimes find it hard to make out the white text on the black background, so I would like to be able to change this to make it more readable.

So how can I change the tooltip color or font in the Ambiance theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Appearance`. In `Themes` select the `Ambiance` theme and hit the `Customize...` button.

[image]

In the just popped up `Customize Theme` window select the `Colors` tab.

[image]

Now edit the colors to your desired value. The `Tooltips` colors are highlighted on the screenshot.

*Note: I'm using 10.10 but it should be similar on 10.04*

Comment: Any idea how to do that in 11.10?

Comment: just answered my own question: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11345748&postcount=2 - Modify the /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc file. In the gtk-color-scheme string at the very top of the file, change the tooltip_bg_color and selected_fg_color entries and add a tooltip_fg_color entry.

Comment: @Christoph Maybe you want to post that as a separate question & answer so it's more discoverable to others? Thanks!

Comment: good idea. I provided an additional answer and edited the question. Imo, a separate question would fragment too much.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10/Oneiric, the method changed, since the configuration dialog is not available anymore.

Modify the /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc file. In the gtk-color-scheme string at the very top of the file, change the tooltip_bg_color and selected_fg_color entries and add a tooltip_fg_color entry.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11345748&postcount=2